# fgetcsv does not returning an array

Tags: php

i wrote a simple script which will load a csv file, but the fgetcsv but returning an array, so i can't use foreach loop to do something like searching.

```
$f_pointer=fopen("table.csv","r"); // file pointer

while(!feof($f_pointer)) {


    $ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);

    foreach ($ar as $str1) {

         //Warning:Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
    }


}
```

if the foreach run, there is an error, but very strange, if i use print_r($ar), it will print the csv as one array one line

anyone know what is the problem?

table.csv (in utf8 format)

```
時裝,上衣,襯衫,Shirt,Top * 10 row
```

full code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<?php

$search = array('時裝','女裝','上衣');

$cat1 = "";
$cat2 = "";


$f_pointer=fopen("table.csv","r"); // file pointer

while(! feof($f_pointer)) {


    $ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
    //echo print_r($ar); // print the array 
    $i = 0;

    //echo count($ar);
    if (is_array($ar)) {
        foreach ($ar as $str1) {
            echo trim($str1);
            // will print full str 時裝上衣襯衫ShirtTop
            /*if (trim($str[$i]) == $search[$i]) {
                if ($i == 1 )
                    $cat1 = $str[3];

                if ($i == 2)
                    $cat2 = $str[4];
            }

            $i++;
            if ($i == 3) break;*/
            //echo $str;

        }
    }


    echo "<br>";

}

echo 'cat1='.$cat1.'<br>';
echo 'cat2='.$cat2.'<br>';


?>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you print_r(fgetcsv($f_pointer)) first and show the output?

Comment: Array ( [0] => 時裝 [1] => 上衣 [2] => 襯衫 [3] => Shirt [4] => Top ) 1

Comment: Edited my comment above.

Comment: I've tested your code in my machine except adding `<?php` and `?>` and it's working!

Comment: @hkguile, it's again working in my machine. which OS are you using for this?

Comment: windows 8 , xampp,

Comment: the same as me. are you still getting `Warning:Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`?

Comment: yes, $ar is not an array , why?

Comment: @hkguile, maybe you have problem in reading the file, check if the file is correctly read first.

Answer (score 0):

array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\" ]]]] )

What's is your delimiter ? and enclosure ?

Comment: What do you mean?!

Comment: the question has been updated and also it's not mine! Your answer also is a question not an answer though. refer to [answer]

Comment: It's working...array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(6) "時裝"
  [1] =>
  string(6) "上衣"
  [2] =>
  string(6) "襯衫"
  [3] =>
  string(5) "Shirt"
  [4] =>
  string(12) "Top * 10 row"
} OS used ?

Comment: I've got no error running it either but the person who asked have!

Comment: What is th OS used for that ?

Comment: @Rafael Moreno, print_r will print an array, but in for each, it prints a str

Comment: @hkguile, sorry... you mean a string that contains all value in one line ? It is not the case... string(6) "時裝"
string(6) "上衣"
string(6) "襯衫"
string(5) "Shirt"
string(12) "Top * 10 row"

Comment: print_r($ar); will print an array Array ( [0] => 時裝 [1] => 上衣 [2] => 襯衫 [3] => Shirt [4] => Top ), but in foreach will print 時裝上衣襯衫ShirtTop

Comment: Yes... and it's not an error... check your loop...  foreach ($ar as $str1) {... in this case... $str1 is a STRING... and then... $str[$i]... it's a string not an array... why you don't have any issue with that ? because you can use [ ] for string too... exemple : $test = "test"; $test[0] --> 't'